# What is the place where we write code and the right menu called in Brackets?

Tags: menu, ide, adobe-brackets

I use brackets but I don't know the names of the place where you write code

[image: the place where you write code]

and the right bar that contains some buttons (e.g Live Preview and Extension Manager)  menus.

[image: the right bar that contains some buttons (e.g Live Preview and Extension Manager)]

Comment: They're the editor window and a toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

The red thing you marked is called editor. The left menu and right panel are called toolbars or sidebars.

Honestly you don't even need to know these menu names (maybe except the editor).